# How to store data that is specific to users with firebase?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

On the application I am developing, the user creates their account with e-mail and password but how can I make data specific to the user? For example, in my application a user can gain points by completing certain tasks. So when a user completes a task, I need to update their points and store it on the database so they can gain points overtime and use them to redeem awards. Here is what I think I am supposed to do, but I am unsure if I have to add anything to the rules or not.
[image]

[image]

Note: Every user's point amount is supposed to be unique to that specific user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want users to only be able to read/write their own data, you'll want to store that data under the user's UID. From the Firebase documentation on [securely accessing user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication):

> Another common pattern is to make sure users can only read and write their own data:
>
> ```
> service cloud.firestore {
>   match /databases/{database}/documents {
>     // Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches name of the user
>     // document. The wildcard expression {userId} makes the userId variable
>     // available in rules.
>     match /users/{userId} {
>       allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
>       allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

yup looks good, just be careful about who has access to write to that document.